Why is oldValue ALWAYS undefined upon entering function onEdit?
In my script, I want to compare the value that has just been entered into a cell with whatever value was previously in that cell, if any.
Per https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events, oldValue should be defined if (a) the edited range is a single cell and (b) the cell did actually previously contain a value. But this assertion does not bear out in practice, at least not per my attempts: instead, the value of oldValue is ALWAYS undefined.
I selected a cell that contained the word "Rome", I then typed the word "Paris" and hit the Return key.
My onEdit function contains, for debugging purposes, the following lines of script:
.
function onEdit(event) {
...
  const valueBeforeEdit = event.oldvalue;
  const valueAfterEdit = event.value;
...
  outputDebuggingMsg("valueAfterEdit = " + valueAfterEdit +
                  "\n valueBeforeEdit = " + valueBeforeEdit);
...

*outputDebuggingMsg is a function I wrote to write useful data to successive rows of my "Debugging Messages" sheet, so I can later view a long series of such data.
The trouble is, the debugging output message is always as follows:
  valueAfterEdit = Paris
  valueBeforeEdit = undefined  (I expected it to say "Rome" not "undefined")

Ths same thing happens whether I try this in Chrome [version 131.0.6778.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)] OR Edge [version 131.0.2903.86 (Official build) (64-bit)].

You have an error typo that's why the output is always undefined, change your function valueBeforeEdit = event.oldvalue to oldValue.

Error cause by typo
You have an error typo that's why the output is always undefined, change your function valueBeforeEdit = event.oldvalue to oldValue.
From this:
const valueBeforeEdit = event.oldvalue;

To this:
const valueBeforeEdit = event.oldValue;

You can read more about simple triggers and installable triggers on this link - Event Objects.

Thank you so much, Lime Husky!
I'm embarrassed that I did not notice that case-sensitive typo error myself!

If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvote the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. how to accept the answer.
